Question about moving Hodge $\star$ to the argument of a 1-form
Let $\alpha$ be a 1-form on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ and $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ (1-)vectors in $V$. Is it true that
$$
\star \alpha(v_1,...,v_{n-1}) = \alpha\big(\star(v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_{n-1})\big)?
$$
I would think that this is true since it seems to me that it does not matter whether one takes the complement of the "measuring tool" $\alpha$ or the volume to be measured, $v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_{n-1}$, but I would not be able to come up with a rigorous proof of this.

Of course you meant to say that $V$ is an oriented inner product space. Have you tried checking your claim with orthonormal basis vectors and covectors? There may be a factor of $\pm1$ you should check, too.

Right, I didn't check anything, it was simply a gut feeling that moving the Hodge star to the argument would work. I will try checking it later. But it is nice to hear that it does not sound completely outlandish.

It seems to work, I tested it on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\star dx^1 (\partial_2,\partial_3) = dx^1\big(\star (\partial_2 \wedge \partial_3)\big)$.

Try $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^4$. If I warned you about a sign, parity of dimension is crucial.
